# iSCSI Packet Header

Tags: networking, tcp, packet, scsi, iscsi

Does iSCSI introduce any layers (other than the TCP-headers themselves) on top of the SCSI packet? Are there any reference manuals for iSCSI other than the RFC itself? I need this information for controlling a RF-receiver over a Paralan iSCSI-to-SCSI-converter.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211794/iscsi-data-transport-packet-overhead

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are a number of functions that iSCSI must implement (to name the least, authentication and authorization) on top of standard SCSI functions.

The iSCSI PDU format is outlined in Chapter 10 of [RFC 3720 - iSCSI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3720#page-112)

In terms iSCSI of reference material, I like [Storage Networks Explained, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470741430); this is a 2009 revision of the well-regarded [first edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470861827)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this book "iSCSI: The Universal Storage Connection".

Answer (score 0):

Everything is TCP. iSCSI has its own headers in the PDUs. Authentication and authorization are not required by iSCSI. But the initiator and/or target is allowed require authentication. Regarding extra headers over SCSI, there is a negotiation process which is not SCSI. Once the negotiation is over iSCSI enters "full feature phase". At that point the headers will be specific to SCSI.

Since it is just TCP then it should pass directly through to your converter. But you converter will probably need to handle the negotiation process. Once it enters full feature phase you will have to deal with too much to describe here; it is not a simple matter of just passing SCSI stuff.

Basically a converter would be an "iSCSI Target" and then the CDB, LUN, TMF's, etc are passed to the SCSI layer. You will have to build up a data interface because your SCSI layer must ask your target layer to receive data, transmit data, handle TMF's and so on. It is the most complex driver I have ever written. If you need a layer I could supply you one that is system independent. You would then write interface routines for your system.